# Weird warping Raphael rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, raphael

I have used Raphael to success to 5 different pointers in my view. These pointers can rotate 360 degrees and do this randomly. But one acts a bit weird (the biggest pointer). When it starts rotating sometimes it minimizes and sort of cheats to get to the other rotation point. So it doesn't make a full rotation but it scales itself to the center point and then scales itself to the exit point.

This is how I initialize the pointer:

```
this.canvas = Raphael(document.getElementById('pointer-4'), 126, 126);
this.pointer = this.canvas.image(WEBROOT + 'img/comparator/gauge/pointer-4.png', (126 / 2) - 41, (126 / 2) - 10, 60, 14);
```

Then I initialize it to the startpoint:

```
this.pointer.stop().animate({transform: ['R', -60, (126 /2), (126 /2)]}, 1300, 'bounce');
```

This is the rotation part:

```
var randomRotation = Math.random() * 280 - 60;
var randomDuration = Math.random() * 700 + 1300;
this.pointer.stop().animate({transform: ['R', randomRotation, (126 / 2), (126 / 2) - 3]}, randomDuration, 'bounce');
```

Hope anybody has had the same problem and knows where it comes from.

Comment: Need code demo to really know, but try it with a lowercase 'r'.

Comment: Doesn't resolve it...

Comment: Need a jsfiddle to play with, sounds like its looking for shortest route to your target degree.